# How to change the x-axis ticks on ggboxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I have a ggboxplot that looks like this:

[image: ggboxplot]

I would like to change the x-axis ticks for the box plots to read "Uncontrolled Disease" and "Controlled Disease" instead of "Progressive" and "Stable". I've tried to use scale_x_discrete:

```
ggboxplot(inf, x = "DiseaseStatus", y = "log.IL-1RA", 
          color = "DiseaseStatus", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
          ylim = c(-2,8),
          order = c("Progressive", "Stable"),
          scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Uncontrolled Disease", "Controlled Disease")),
          main = "IL-1RA",
          ylab = "log lab value", xlab = "DiseaseStatus")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in !is.null(facet.by) | combine : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to change the x-axis ticks?

Comment: Try removing the `scale_x_discrete` argument and adding if after the plot. Your last line should be `ylab = "log lab value", xlab = "DiseaseStatus") +` and the following line `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Uncontrolled Disease", "Controlled Disease"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
ggboxplot(inf, x = "DiseaseStatus", y = "log.IL-1RA", 
          color = "DiseaseStatus", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
          ylim = c(-2,8),
          order = c("Progressive", "Stable"),
          main = "IL-1RA",
          ylab = "log lab value", xlab = "DiseaseStatus") +
          scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Uncontrolled Disease", "Controlled Disease"))
```

I used test data becuase I didnt have your data. This is the code I used

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth


ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Uncontrolled Disease", "Controlled Disease", "third variable"))
```

[image: Test Data Boxplot]